# how can i handle Java pass-by-value? i need pass-by-reference

Tags: java, datatable, pass-by-value

I have such piece of code:

```
DataTableFactory<Object> TempDataTableFactory = new DataTableFactory<Object>();
DataTable<Object> tempDataTable = TempDataTableFactory.getInstance();
tempDataTable = dataTable;
ExecutedArguments e = new ExecutedArguments(); 
e.setDataTable(tempDataTable);
e.setExecutedCommand(cmd);
stack.addNewExecutedCommand(e);
result = operation.execute();
```

Now I just want to keep the `olddataTable` before execution. When I debug my code till the line `result = operation.execute();` there is no problem. In that line I change the `dataTable`. But because `tempDataTable` points to `dataTable` it also changes. But I don't want `tempDataTable` to change. How can I do this?

Comment: This has ... nothing to do with pass-by-value or pass-by-reference.

Comment: @Brian I'm not sure that's true. If it was pass by value, the entire object would get passed but not modified in the calling procedure, wouldn't it?

Comment: Java is *only* pass by value. It just so happens the value is a memory address ;) Aside from that ... I really can't make heads or tails of his question and why that has anything to do with the price of tea in China :)

Comment: @Brian I know that Java is strictly pass by value; but if the object was passed by value instead of the reference, his problem would be solved without code changes. But of course, you can't, so you have to `clone` it or something similar and pass your clone in.

Answer (score 2):

If it supports cloning, I would use `tempDataTable.clone()`. Otherwise you'll have to implement a copy constructor.